# Facebook Open Graph Story only visible for me

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Open Graph Stories to share information from my iOS App.

The Story is showing properly in MY Feed.

But not in the timeline of my friends. Even if they open my FB profile, they can't see my posted story.

My posted story is 'public' and I enabled public usage of my app:

[image]

How can I make it visible to all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it visible, you have to submit in review from Facebook.
Follow the instructions here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/

Meanwhile, only admins, developers and testers of your app can see your posts.

Comment: Thanks, so I just have to click this "Start a Submission" button? Do you have any experience, how long this review process takes?

Comment: You have to meet the conditions explained in the link before clicking 'Start a Submission' to be sure you're ok. The review process can take 3 working days.

Comment: Unless the "status and review" page shows up blank. A known bug that they don't care to fix. How annoying is that ?! https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256836961156524/